# Can I copy files from a PC to an iMac using a USB memory stick?

Tags: macos, usb

Having been a PC user for a number of years I'm now seriously considering purchasing an Apple iMac (21.5″, 2.7 GHz). Is it possible to use a USB flash drive to copy files from my Windows 7 PC to the iMac?

Comment: most of them but not all of them.

Comment: "most of them but not all of them"? I've never ran into or even heard of a USB flash drive that doesn't work with OS X.

Comment: @Buscar Whilst I understand you've only given a comment and not an answer, could you be far more specific with your comments or provide a source as opposed to your generalised statements?

Comment: If you have Windows only app files (you can copy them) but those wont work on OS X without some extra steps.

Comment: Many thanks to all respondents for your valued replies to my question.

Comment: Yes, You can copy files from PC to MAC. No issue at all.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely you can copy files from a USB thumb drive to a Mac. They're typically formatted as MS-DOS partitions which a Mac can read and write.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a way to do that while taking care of the logistics.

Yes you could use USB flash drive and then do everything your self (making folders and deciding what files go where and what Apple app will open them ect..) or use Apple provided way, with either WiFi or Cable or manual method.

> [Moving from your PC to your new Mac? Consider it done](https://www.apple.com/osx/what-is/compatibility/).
>
> With OS X, you can move all the information from your old PC to your
>   new Mac.
>
> Built-in Windows-to-Mac migration in OS X automatically transfers
>   your documents, music, contacts, calendars, and email accounts
>   (Outlook and Windows Live Mail), and puts them in the appropriate
>   folders and applications on your new Mac. Just like that.
>
> <sub>If you buy your Mac at an Apple Retail Store, Personal Setup can help
>   you get off to a great start. And with a One to One membership, an
>   Apple Genius can even transfer your files from your PC and show you
>   how to use all the great apps that come on your Mac.</sub>

[More information here:](http://support.apple.com/en-us/ht2518)

Comment: Thank you Buscar for providing details of an alternative method of moving files from my PC to an iMac.